# SWT: Changing the color of all the cells under a column

Tags: eclipse, colors, swt

[image]

I've search around the web but have seen no answer. How can you change the color of all the cells under a column much like the first column in the picture? Which as you can see is a darker shade from the second and third column. Now I don't believe changing the TableItem's background will solve this, as it will only change that cell's color, the effect can be seen in the first row.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I suspect, you mean **row**, not **column**.

Comment: No, if you look at the cells of the first column it has a darker shade than the rest. How would you achieve that?

Comment: No, you are confusing the terms. A **row** is horizontal. So the first row is dark grey whereas the other two rows are white. The columns are all the same in you example (See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_(database))). To get back to your question: Are you using a `TableViewer` or a simple `Table`?

Comment: There are three colors in that picture white, light grey, and dark grey. The dark grey (first row) represents the results of editing the color of the TableItem object in a Table object. The light grey (first column) is what I am asking to achieve.

Comment: My apologies. My monitor displays both colors as white. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `Table`, you can color the cells with the method [`TableItem#setBackground(int, Color)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FTableItem.html) where the `int` describes the column index. To color a whole column, you would have to iterate over all `TableItem`s and set the color for that column.

---

If you are using a `TableViewer` (which I would recommend), you can set the color in the `LabelProvider`s `public void update(ViewerCell cell)` method. Just call [`ViewerCell#setBackground(Color)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ViewerCell.html#setBackground%28org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color%29) for the first column. You can get the column index via [`ViewerCell#getColumnIndex()`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ViewerCell.html#getColumnIndex%28%29).

Comment: Ah, I haven't look at TableViewer. I will try it out later tonight.

Comment: @DudeWhoNeedHelp When you did that and think that my answer solved your problem, please upvote and accept it. Good luck.

Comment: I've tried both the proposed solution but the results end up the same.

http://i47.tinypic.com/2wltrfm.jpg

In this image, I've added 5 items and the setBackground only changes the color of the 5 items not the whole column. I'm starting to believe there is no way to change the color of the columns background without adding X items.

Comment: So you are trying to color the area where there are no items? That's not possible with build-in functions. Maybe you could add a `PaintListener` to the table and paint it yourself, but that could get really messy. Or you could fill in empty items and color them.